# How to Mark NTFS filesystem dirty from *NIX/Linux?

Tags: windows, linux, unix, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Is there any way to mark a NTFS-fileystem dirty using ntfstools/ntfs-3g or any other tool, so it gets chkdsk'd when windows boots?
I know I can do that from windows or the recovery console but I'm curious if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unix answer: [man ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix).

Comment: Yes, I know that one. But I don't like the description in the man page: "It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows."
So what "fundamental NTFS inconsistencies" does it repair? I would rather just have it flip that one "do chkdsk" flag and not touch the filesystem in any other way.

Comment: This only clears the dirty flag there isn't a way to force set it it seems.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 'ntfsfix -d DEVICE', optionally followed by 'ntfsfix DEVICE' should set the volume as dirty if there is anything wrong.  ntfsfix attempts to clear the 'dirty' flag, but if it cannot repair and mount the volume then it sets the flag for the next boot into Windows.